# How to attach file(s) in php mailer within same php page?

Tags: php, email, phpmailer, attachment, email-attachments

I am using php mailer to send emails with attachments. I want files to be attached within the same page. my form,

```
<form method="POST" action="#" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 

<label>Files to upload:</label>
<input type="file" name="files[]" multiple/>

<button type="submit" name="btnSend" value="Send">Send</button>

</form>
```

And my php code snippet is,

```
if (isset($_POST['btnSend'])) {
    $mail = new mymailer();
    include DOC_ROOT . 'include/contact-email-template.php';
    $mailArray = array("my-email-address");
    $subject = "Contact Form";
    $from = $email;
    $mail->sendMail($from, $mailArray, $subject, $admin_template);
    $emailsent = 1;
    $mod_email = "Success";

    /* redirect to home after success */
    if ($emailsent == 1) {

        unset($_POST['firstname']);
        unset($_POST['lastname']);
        unset($_POST['email']);
        unset($_POST['phone']);
        unset($_POST['message']);

        $mod_email = "Show";
                }
}
```

How can I attach the file(s) I chose from `input type="file"`
Please help.

**PS:** Emails are sending fine with this code even when I set the action to external file and save chosen image in the disk and attach them. **I just want to know how to attach files within the same page.**

Comment: you have to upload those files to the server first and then attach it to mail

Comment: Look at the ['send file upload' example](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/send_file_upload.phps) provided with PHPMailer.

Answer (score 0):

You can you $_FILES and attach the chosen file into mail body on the same page

```
if(!empty($_FILES)){
    $i = 0;
    foreach($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'] as $file){
        echo $mail->AddAttachment($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$i], $_FILES['files']['name'][$i]);
        $i++;
    }
}
```